# How to repeat ACF Flexible Content on single pages?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Disclaimer: If you have never used ACF Flexible Content to build a site, please reserve the hate and all that - looking just for help.

I'm creating a website that's 100% modular, done with Flexible Content.

I have Pages such as:

```
Home, About, Services, Blog, Portfolio, Contact
```

All of those pages styled using Flexible Content, these are PAGES.

I have created a custom field for Services and Portfolio, and I used WP Query to display each individal item. These are CUSTOM fields. Show this field group if post type to Services. Not a page.

So when you click it, what happens you go to `single-[custom-post-type].php`, however I just have `single.php` to keep it dynamic, which works.

The problem lays that when I have showed the flexible content page templates in the Services or Portfolio, and I add few items, I need go to every single item and set the layout.

How can I do so the layout stays all the same in Service or Portfolio custom field?

Comment: Where's your code? Show us what you've done so far. It's too hard to tell what you are asking without seeing an example.

Comment: It's normal ACF Flexible Content code. It's just like if you were doing it, at least on the back-end side, the UI in the admin dashboard. However, the code is here: https://github.com/AurelianSpodarec/aurelianMegaPortfolio2018

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking, do you mean you want to show the flexible content fields on all portfolio and services pages without needing to change the template?

Comment: Not pages, custom fields. When you create a Service custom fileds, you can add new items, like 'Brand desing', 'Web Dev' etc... I need them to assing a flexible content, but they all need to use the same layout. So I set the layout on one, and they need to be exactly the same on every single.php page.

Comment: Do you have something else than stack? Would be easier to explain and show examples : p

Comment: I know what he means. You would be able to achieve this by either using ACF Options page and creating the blocks in there. And calling them with the relevant code, or you can call the fields and input a post id parameter in order to retrieve the same data as that post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly create your ACF Master block, for example, a testimonial section, this would have the repeater fields inside the block etc. In this example, we will call it Testimonial Master.

Then Create another Flexible Content Field Called Testimonial Block with a checkbox that you check to display or hide.

You will now populate Testimonial Master on your selected Parent Page or on an Options page. You then should add the Testimonial Block to any page you are looking to have that block appear on.

You will then went to check that the Testimonial Block is on the page, if it is on the page then you will check if Testimonial Master has a value if it has a value then you can pull in the values from Testimonial Master.

```
<?php 
    if( have_rows('page_structure') ):
    while ( have_rows('page_structure') ) :
    the_row();
        if( get_row_layout() == 'testimonial_block' ):
         if( get_sub_field('testimonial_block_toggle') == 'show' ):?>
             <div class="testimonials">
                <?php the_sub_field('testimonial_master_title', 1); ?>
             </div>
         <?php endif;
        endif;
    endwhile;
    endif;
?>
```

The "1" is the page ID, use this if you have populated the field on a master page. Or if you are using the ACF Options Page plugin change the "1" to "'options'".

Here is some further documentation on getting values from other posts including that of repeater fields.

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-get-values-from-another-post/

**Edit: Custom Header as per your example**

Make a custom header file and add your code for that header block.

Now make an advanced custom field for a text area. For example header_text_block, set it to a WYSIWYG editor.

Now in your code just use:

```
<?php the_field('header_text_block');?>
```

This will then use the exact same header on every page you pull it into, however it will let you edit the text individually for each page.

**Edit: Example of what this code looks like and does**

Also I think you are very confused, there will only be 1 php/html file? you could use page.php.

Here's an example of what I am saying, 1 php file:

```
<?php if( have_rows('page_structure') ):

        while ( have_rows('page_structure') ) : the_row();  

            if( get_row_layout() == 'page_featured' ):
                $image = get_sub_field('page_featured_image');
                    if( !empty($image) ):?>
                        <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>">
                    <?php endif;
            endif;

            if( get_row_layout() == 'page_breadcrumbs' ):

                if( !in_array( 'hide', get_sub_field('page_breadcrumbs_hide') ) ):?>
                    <?php if ( function_exists('yoast_breadcrumb') ) {yoast_breadcrumb('<p id="breadcrumbs">','</p>');}?>
                <?php else :
                endif;
            endif;
        endwhile;
    endif;
?>
```

This then looks like this on the page editor:

[image: ACF Flexible Content]

You can then edit each section as you please and also drag and drop sections where you want them which enables easy split testing.

All the styling will be the same, just you can change the content and if you wanted you could add the ability to alter stylings pretty easily. And it only uses 1 PHP file for the template.

Comment: I think this is the way to go. However, how could I reuse the Master Block? I don't want the sub field of testomonial, but just master. Imagine you have a header or a master header that is on every single page, you have the_title() and then the subfield, which is sub title, why would I need to create another same component for it and call is testimonial sub title, and do this three times for other pages? That'll be reduntant and messy in the long term run. These components should be reusable and easy to update. I know that what you wrote is somewhat the solution to go, but what about that?

Comment: Without using ACF Options, you would need to have a specific page that you alter the master block on such as page id 1. You could instead check if the field is empty on the master page however that would mean you have no control over which sections show on pages as they would show all sections in the same order if they're filled out. My route allows you to alter the structure on each page as well as which blocks appear whilst using the content from the master block.

Comment: But what about reusability? I don't want to create 10different headers that are 100% the same, but have thier own .html file or .php file in this case - if it's possible, I know it is for sure. If you look here - https://rolleragency.co.uk/our-projects/ you see the page is named out-projects, however, if you hower over the project, it's name is project - and all of the pages are customized using one code, one template. I know because I worked on this site, but I didn't had enough time to look on how it's fully build, but I created a new template, new features, and it all worked magically : p

Comment: I kinda get the idea, just trying to wrap my head around this.

Comment: I think you're getting very confused. That link literally shows the same header? just use <?php the_header();?> or make a custom header for these pages.

Comment: Also my example only uses 1 PHP file for the template.. I'm not sure where you are getting the multiple different php files?

Comment: The header is a jumbotron, it's not an actuall header, the header it's just the links. It's like a banner. So I have different banners. Well, I'm confused on how you said to create master testimonials or master portfolio while coping the master block. That would mean coping the master block, will result on having new code like while testimonials block if has page-main or page-half whatever, display it? : p I'm getting confused xd

Comment: This is my code, and the templates should be reusable in all the pages - https://github.com/AurelianSpodarec/aurelianMegaPortfolio2018/tree/master/templates

Comment: But I think it's something like what you did there :D I think this might be some learning curve to understand it :D I'm pretty new to WP as well.

Comment: <?php if ( get_field( 'header_option' ) == 1 ) { 
 the_field( 'header_block' ); 
} else { ?>
 <section class="page-intro">

 <!-- <div class="page-intro__img js-parallax" data-parallax-speed="0.4" style="background-image: url(<?php the_sub_field('background_image'); ?>);"> -->
 <div class="page-intro__overlay"></div>

 <div class="page-intro__content js-parallax" data-parallax-speed="0.4">
 <div class="page-intro__content-outer">

  <h1 class="page-intro__title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
  <!-- <span class="page-intro__sub-title"><?php the_sub_field('subtitle'); ?></span> -->

Comment: </div>
 </div>
 
</section> 
<?php } ?>

Comment: So how would you make that to be reusable with one template? So confused xd

Comment: Aaaaaaa, so Master Block you called them Testimonial Master. However, what I need is to have one master Block for everything. That incudes testimonial, services, portfolio etc... so I'm using just one Master Block for all.

Comment: The other thing is that this also needs to be used with the custom post types. Meaning, I have a page Services, and I ahve a custom post type where I create Services items, were I can Wp_Query the items on the page. Each of these items has different content, but they should have the same layout, this is what I'm trying to do. So when I set the 'Add row' flexbile content in one service item, it should repeat and be the same on every Service Page.

Comment: I think that actually, since I need to use single.php, the default or backfall is there is no single, is index.php, right, which means I need to put that code in the page and single php, since I want to modify single page with this code, not page.php as I know how to do that, problem is to modify the single.php page. Umm

Comment: What you would do is add the copy to something like content-box.php then where you would normally call in the the content to your template. Call in the the content-box, this means you then can use it in any templated page just by calling it and it can be edited in 1 file.

Comment: Anything else you need help with?

Comment: But how will I have flexible content to repeat on single.php page that I can modify it once? xd Do you have skype or something like that perhaps? If you have time. I can't wrap my head on how I'd do this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168805/discussion-between-daniel-vickers-and-aurelian-spodarec).